# .Net Control.Tag - Common and Unusual Uses

Tags: .net, controls

As my program grows and grows, I've been finding I'm using `Control.Tag` more and more. I'm not really sure why Microsoft put it there, but I find it quite useful.

I'm left wondering: What was their original purpose? What is considered acceptable and what is considered taboo?

According to MSDN, `Control.Tag` "Gets or sets the object that contains data about the control."

In my calendar application, I store the actual `Appointment` object which an `AppointmentControl` represents. I suspect this is the intended use of it and the example on MSDN would seem to confirm this, however I also do some more unusual things.

For example, when I have a back/next pair of buttons and I want back to be disabled when we reach the start, and next to be disabled when we reach the end, then I store the next button in the Tag of the previous, and the previous button in the Tag of the next. That way, I can always set the `((Button)Tag).Enabled = true` on click (Because when you move back, clearly a disabled next button will become enabled, and vice-versa).

Also, my calendar is made up of a (visually) two-dimensional array of Panels. I store the `DateTime` which each panel corresponds to in the `Panel.Tag`, and when the user zooms in to see the time slots in a day, the Panels which make up each timeslot has a TimeSpan in their Tag which represents the start time of the slot.

So I'm curious: What do you think is the most common use of Tag? What is a more unusual application of Tag you have used or seen? Would you consider storing a linked object (as in my back/next button example) to be "hacky"?

Some people oppose the use of Tags, suggesting that they are remnants of older languages. A common complaint is that it is better to simply extend a control so that it contains a strongly-typed object rather than something arbitrary which needs to be cast when used. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This came from VB6, its controls had a Tag property as well.  It is a very poor substitute for a field in your class, it isn't type safe since Tag is of type Object.  Makes your code hard to read too, it has a non-specific name.  If you need it to be associated with the control then use inheritance.  Derive a class from the control type and add the properties you need.  Or add a field to your form.